# Travelling to Northern Ireland from Republic of Ireland

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, borders, ireland, northern-ireland

I am a non EU National and currently residing in Ireland. I intend to travel to Northern Ireland (i.e. Belfast) by road and also possess a UK Standard Visitor Visa. Is there any Immigration Control where I have to stop and get my Passport Stamp if I travel by road?

Comment: http://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/republic-of-ireland/gardai-man-border-checkpoints-to-grab-illegals-entering-from-northern-ireland-31449642.html https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Travel-g186591-s602/Ireland:Crossing.The.Border.html Arriving from Northern Ireland: no passport controls are enforced. The border between the Republic of Ireland and Northern Ireland is open and barely discernable. Normally no passport is needed when driving or travelling by train or bus from one into the other

Comment: But still there would be some regulation for Visa required countries ... any checks?

Comment: @engqureshi Possibly, but it is indeed very easy to enter Northern Ireland illegally. At small village crossings, the chance of being checked is virtually zero.

Comment: @GayotFow : "you do NOT get the full 6 months leave-to-enter" ... what does this means?

Comment: Extended discussion is getting too long. Deleting comments and suggest continue in chat

Comment: @GayotFow Created a chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/56384/irish-resident-entering-northern-ireland-uk?tab=general

Comment: @GayotFow .. sorry to tag you. I have unfortunately missed your live chat room discussion ... however, i have seen the Transcript. It was quite confusing for me. So, i also posted my queries there. I am not sure if the chat room is still active or i should post my queries here again.

Comment: @engqureshi The rules are unfortunately not clear, but assuming you're a visa national (again, you haven't told us your nationality - non-visa nationals also can and do get visas for various reasons), you will get something called "terms of visa applies" the meaning of which I do not know. However, most likely you'll get to stay in the UK for approx. 3 months, but again, very individual and up to the immigration officer checking you (if any).

Comment: @Crazydre ... is this "terms of visa applies" mentioned on the Immigration Stamp of the Visa Officer or is it something specified on the Visa Sticker. Secondly, if I fly from Dublin to London, do we have to cross any Immigration Control? Various posts on this and other forums suggests that it is considered as a domestic flight

Comment: @engqureshi Don't know I'm afraid, this is just what others told me. Also, no, there's no immigration when flying to the UK from Ireland (but there is when flying back to Ireland). However, the airline will check your paperwork.

Comment: Well, this is pretty strange. I know several non-EU residents in Ireland, i.e. either for work or study purpose and in possession of UK Standard Visitor Visa too, and they had travelled extensively to UK for over many years now but have never came across this "terms of visa" thing.

If I am not mistaken, every visa has its "terms of visa". And in case of Standard Visitor Visa (i.e. 6 months multiple entry), the "terms of visa" should imply that a Visa Holder can travel for any number of times during those 6 months. Isn't so?

Answer (score 7):

The UK has zero checks at the Irish land border, nor does your passport need to be stamped. As you hold a valid visa, you'll be a legal entrant